# z3py optimization as variables chosen from a list

Tags: z3, z3py

For the example, how to write code in z3py to maximize value of a+b+c+d as a,b,c,d are all chosen from list [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], which is given as the input. a, b, c, d are distinct values.

```
a, b, c, d = Ints("a b c d")
o = Optimize()
list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
o.maximize(a+b+c+d)
```

how to write code corresponding to choose "a b c d" value from list. The correct out value of a+b+c+d is 26
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```py
from z3 import *

a, b, c, d = Ints("a b c d")
o = Optimize()

list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
vars = [a, b, c, d]

for v in vars:
    o.add(Or([v == e for e in list]))

o.add(Distinct(*vars))

goal = Int("goal")
o.add(goal == a+b+c+d)

o.maximize(goal)
if o.check() == sat:
    print o.model()
else:
    print "not satisfiable"
```

When I run this, I get:

```
$ python a.py
[d = 5, c = 8, b = 6, a = 7, goal = 26]
```

Comment: is it possible to memories the index of a, b, c, d in the list as well? for example: d1 ==4, c1==7, b1==5, a1==6

Comment: Sure. But stack-overflow isn’t a coding service. Ask a separate question showing what you tried how it went to get better help. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example